# Strange behavior with URL fragments and onclick in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

I have run into a strange problem in mobile Safari on my (iOS 4) iPod touch.
The minimum body HTML to demonstrate this problem is:

```
<p>
    <a href="" onclick="event.preventDefault()">Click</a>
</p>
<p id="anchor">
    Anchor
</p>
```

When the page is loaded with no # fragment in the URL, clicking the link executes the onclick javascript, which suppresses the action of the link, and (as expected) nothing happens.

However, if the page is loaded with a valid URL fragment, #anchor in the above example, then clicking on the link causes the page to jump to the paragraph with id 'anchor' (like when the page was initially loaded).

I cannot find a way round this; any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should add that the same behavior is observed if `return false` is used in the `onclick`, and regardless of the URL in the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `href=""` (not correct) is the same as `href="."` (correct) which is the same thing than putting the current url in the href.

If you were just trying to make a button, you could use a `<span>` with some CSS like `cursor: pointer` and such things.